# Is there way to use the variable that tested true in an if statement

Tags: javascript, node.js

I can't explain it much in the title but I'm now stuck with having to test 2 variables for the same value and was wondering is there a way to do something like this.
`var a = 'abc';`
`var b = 'def';`
`if (a=='abc' || b=='abc'){ c = 'z';  }`

Now `c` is the variable that was tested true, so by assigning `a` value to `c` it would assign the value to the variable that tested true in the if statement. `a` and `b` can have different values but both can have the same value aswell.

Answer (score 0):

No, the expression just yields a result value, with no information stored about which subexpression was truthy. (And separately, JavaScript doesn't have *references* to variables [at least, not that you can use in your code].) You'll have to break it out into two `if`s:

```
if (a === "abc") {
    a = "z";
} else if (b === "abc") {
    b = "z";
}
```

---

It would be possible to do something like this if the variables were accessor properties (or other function calls) with side effects (since the right-hand operand of the `||` won't be evaluated at all if the left-hand operand evaluates to a truthy value). Or if they were properties in an object and you tested an array of property names, etc. But it would be unnecessarily complicated. :-)

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer! I just have to wait a few more minutes before I can accept your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could take a [`switch` statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch), here you can check various variables agains a certain value.

```
switch ('abc') {
    case a:
        a = 'z';
        break;
    case b:
        b = 'z';
        break;
}
```